# ClassNotFoundException using JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail, classnotfoundexception

I have created a new project in Netbeans, where I set up a servlet (Tomcat 8) and I want to implement a way to send email with gmail. I found many examples (like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)). I created a class

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail {

final String username = "mymail@gmail.com";
final String password = "pass";

public SendMail() {

}


public void send(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,  //<- points1 here
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
      });

    try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

and in the servlet I called that method

```
SendMail send = new SendMail();
send.send();  //<- points 2
```

And I get an error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger`

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [MyServlet] in context with path [/MyServlet] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
    at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:227)
    at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:212)
    at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:248)
    at com.myPackage.MyServlet.SendMail.send(SendMail.java:35) //->points 1
    at com.myPackage.MyServlet.MyServlet.processRequest(MyServlet.java:77) //->points 2 
    at com.myPackage.MyServlet.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.myPackage.MyServlet.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I have added the 2 jars `javaee.jar` and `mail.jar` in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing multiple versions of JavaMail.  The javaee.jar [only includes the API classes for compiling not execution](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0).  The mail.jar is going to be an old version of JavaMail. If you require just JavaMail then [download the javax.mail.jar](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release) and use that instead.

Comment: Actually, the javavee.jar only contains the JavaMail APIs, not the full implementation.  That will work fine for compiling your application (which is what it's intended for), but to run your application you need the full implementation jar referenced above.